# How to calculate the expected value of complex-valued random variable?

Tags: pr.probability, cv.complex-variables

Suppose $\theta_1,\theta_2,\cdots, \theta_n$ are **independent** and identically distributed (i.i.d.) real-valued random variables and here we specifically consider the **uniform distribution** in the interval $[0,1]$. 
Then how to calculate the expected value of the following variable which is function of $\theta_1,\theta_2,\cdots, \theta_n$.

The **target variable** is: $|e^{j 2\pi(\theta_1-\theta_2)}+e^{j 2\pi(\theta_3-\theta_4)}+\cdots+e^{j 2\pi(\theta_{n-1}-\theta_n)}|$.
Here, $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm, $j^2=-1$ and $|\cdot|$ is the absolute value symbol.

**About**: This is not a homework problem. I met it when I try to calculate the expectation of $|g\star g|$, where $\star$ is the correlation operator and $|\cdot|$ represents element-wise absolute. $g$ ($g_{i,j}=e^{j2\pi\theta_{i,j}}$) is an $N\times N$ complex-valued random matrix, where $\theta_{i,j}$ are i.i.d. real random variables,

Comment: The square of your variable is easy to estimate: it's just $n$. (This is the square distance of a random walk taking unit size steps in random directions is from the origin after $n$ steps). This random variable is fairly tightly bounded. It's variance is $n$, so that its standard deviation is $\sqrt n$. This means that the squared-variable takes values $n\pm \sqrt n$, so that your variable itself is close to $\sqrt n$.  on average.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas I found my question is related to random walk in two-dimensional plane. The [answer by Henry](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103142/expected-value-of-random-walk/103170#103170) is what I thought a possible solution to it, but he didn't provide any reference for further reading and citing. How may I contact [Henry](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/6460/henry) for help?

Answer (score 1):

I am using $i=\sqrt{-1}$ instead of $j.$

Use induction, noting the differences $\theta_l-\theta_k$ are themselves uniformly distributed, so might as well just use a single $\theta_k$ in each term. For a single complex exponential the expectation is $M_1=1$.

Then find $$M_2=\mathbb{E}\left[|1+\exp(2\pi i \theta)|\right]=\mathbb{E} \left[\sqrt{(1+\cos(2\pi\theta))^2+\sin^2(2\pi\theta )}\right]$$
by integration. Whatever this mean is, and it will have a $\sin()\times\cos()$
type of term once you expand, you then add the new complex exponential term to it. So, $$M_3=\mathbb{E} \left[\sqrt{(M_2+\cos(2\pi\theta))^2+\sin^2(2\pi\theta )}\right]$$ and the integral is essentially the same.

Comment: I found my question is related to random walk in two-dimensional plane. The answer by [Henry ](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103142/expected-value-of-random-walk/103170#103170) is what I thought a possible solution to it, but he didn't provide any reference for further reading and citing. How may I contact @Henry for help?